# Lazy Load só carrega dados quando restarto a solution

Tags: c#

Galera, estou com o seguinte problema: Quando faço o Entity Framework adicionar um dado na base, ele faz, mas não me retorna os atributos do tipo Class carregados. Para que as mesmas carreguem normalmente, preciso reestartar a solution.

O meu mapeamento está correto... Minha entidade está como Virtual e o mapeamento da classe e do DTO está correto.

Alguém tem uma dica do que fazer?

Comment: Apresente o seu código

Comment: "_mas não me retorna os atributos do tipo Class carregados_" O que isso quer dizer, exatamente?

Answer (score 0):

Eu conheço duas configurações importantes quando se trata de Lazy Load e que me ajudaram ao longo do tempo:

1) Reiterar na configuração do contexto:

Exemplo:

```
   contexto.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

2) Quando a classe tiver relacionamentos, você deve incluí-las [.Include(x => x.{COLECAO})]:

Exemplo:

```
   var produtos = _contexto.Produtos
                           .Where(p => p.Name == "Camisa")
                           .Include(x => x.Cores)
                           .ToList();
```

Espero que ajude.